Help with AC Unit placement
this summer i finally mastered up the will to buy and AC unit, it will be on the secound floor in the house. The floor has roughly 60 square meter in size or 645 square feet. The goal of AC would be to reduce temperature on whole floor if possible, with main goal to reduce most temp in room 1 as its most often used through the day, the other two rooms are mostly sleeping rooms. Is this possible with AC being on the spots i pinned in Hallway or is there some better spot?
EDIT: To clarify its 1 AC unit that is wall mounted( the ones that have  condenser unit on the outside wall behind them) , size of unit will be appropriate for size of the floor, and we have no air ducts in the house.
Floor layout

I'd just like to point out that most of the cool air will go down the stairs unless you take steps to keep the cool air on the second floor. One method that I've seen is to place a temporary wall-to-wall, floor-to-ceiling curtain on a tension rod at the top of the stairs. A door would be more effective.

What type of unit?, central, window, wall.  Will you install duct work?  size of unit?

This is two units, one in each spot?  Or one unit, pick one spot?

Just updated my post with more info

It sounds like you are using a PTAC unit like are used in hotel rooms.  They are sub-optimal for cooling an entire floor.
If the goal is to cool room 1 the most, put the unit in room 1 and leave the door open. This will not cool the entire floor evenly. Some rooms may not feel cooler at all. However you are trying to achieve a result that your chosen unit is not designed for.
If you can, switch to a mini split system the temp in each room can be adjusted and if the doors are open the cold air will cool the halls.
